# Finding IP Address From Operation Contract Message in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I just came across an article that mentions a method to find the Client IP Address without specifying required ASP.Net Compatibility mode.

It requires doing the following:

```
        var msgprops = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
        var clientprop = msgprops[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        string clientip=clientprop.Address;
```

Is there any downside to doing this method? If so, what is a fix, and if the fix is using the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute, then will I run into any problems such as performance or compatibility?